# image printed in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress

I found this img src

http://pixel.wp.com/g.gif?v=ext&j=1%3A4.3.1&blog=127730128&post=2&tz=0&srv=hurbtrade.com&host=mywebsite.com&ref=&rand=0.8617862838961312

the wired thing this is generated form wordpress website 
the image for a skull so any one know what is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try fetching this image by entering its URL directly in your browser.
I get a tiny gif that is a mere 6 by 5 pixels in size.

The typical use of "pixel images" is for ad/visitor tracking and statistics between different sites. The request parameters that are included in the URL, along with HTTP REFERER inform the pixel provider (in this case wp.com) about the page-view. If the visitor to your site happens to be known to the pixel issuer, then in the request they'll also get a cookie that informs them WHO the visitor is.
This can be used for statistics. 
This can be used to track effectiveness of ads (conversion rates after someone clicked on an ad and went to a landing page, for instance).
This can be used to track your interests (do you visit a lot of sites about motor cycles or swimming?), etc.

This way you can have tracking pixels from several issuers on one page.

The issuer wp.com (i.e. WordPress.com) is a hint that the site uses Jetpack and probably its included statistics package.

Comment: Good answer, including the mention of Jetpack. Since the original post mentioned the image of a skull, just to clarify, it's just a simple smile face if viewed on a white background.